# Verify that R(p,2) = R(2,p) = p, where R is the Ramsey number

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

> Verify that $R(p,2) = R(2,p) = p$, where $R$ is the Ramsey number

It just seems obvious that $R(p,2) = R(2,p)$.

But why do  $R(p,2)$ and  $R(2,p)$ both equal p?

Comment: What have you tried? "It seems obvious" isn't really enough for soliciting help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$R(2,p)=p$ because either all of the edge choices $\{x,y\}$ are colored $1$, or there are some $2$ elements $x_0,y_0\in V$ such that $\chi(\{x_0,y_0\})=2$. Remember, a choice of two vertices is a choice of an edge.

To expand a bit:  $R(2,p)$ is the smallest number such that the complete graph on $R(2,p)$ nodes has a complete subgraph on $p$ nodes or $2$ nodes. Now, if all the edges are colored $1$ (i.e. the first color) then we have a complete subgraph on $p$ nodes and clearly $R(2,p)\ge p$. If not, then at least one edge is colored with the second color, i.e. $2$. However an edge is EXACTLY a copy of a complete graph on $2$ nodes. If we have at least $p$ nodes, then assuming even one single edge is not colored $1$, we have an edge (i.e. a complete 2-subgraph) of color $2$ guaranteed.

Comment: (a) I don't see how this proves R(2,p)=p. (b). I don't know what you mean by $\chi(\{x_0,y_0\} = 2$. I understand this notation to mean that you need two colors to color one edge.

Comment: No, $\chi$ is the edge coloring, and edges are sets of two elements, so

$$\chi: E\to \{1,2\}$$

$\{x_0,y_0\}\in E$ is an edge in the complete graph on $p$ nodes.

Check my elaboration in the answer to see if that helps.

Comment: So why doesn't R(2,p) = 2? You can always guarantee that with two nodes you can find a complete graph that is 1 colored? Isn't that what we are looking for: the min number of nodes for a complete graph s.t. we can find a complete subgraph that can be one colored?

Comment: No, because you need to also have that it's possible to get a $p$-complete subgraph, and if $p>2$ that's not possible if $|V|=2$.