# Binomial upper bound for the bi-color Ramsey numbers (Erdős-Szekeres)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

> **The question**: How did Erdös - Szekeres came up with a close form with a binomial for the upper bound: Where does the idea behind $R(2,2)=\binom{2+2-2}{2-1}$ -  I do see that $R(2,2)=2$ - or $\binom{s+t-3}{s-1}\left(\text{or }\binom{s+t-3}{s-2}\right)$ come from? And how is the induction over $s$ and $t$ work?
>
> **What I understand:**
>
> 1. I see that $R(s,t) \leq R(s-1,t)+R(s,t-1)$
> 2. I understand that ${\displaystyle  {\binom {r+s-3}{r-2}}+{\binom {r+s-3}{r-1}}={\binom {r+s-2}{r-1}}}$ - Pascal's triangle.
> 3. I also see that $\forall s, t ∈ \mathbb N,$ the relationship $R(s, t) = R(t, s)$ holds.
> 4. And I get it that $R(s,2)=R(2,s)=s.$
>
> **The problem:** There are tons of sites where the proof of the inequality above is readily available, including one of the answers to this post. However, when the inequality is proven, the binomial formula seems to appear out of thin air like it is self-evident, typically with a short justification such as: *easily proven by induction on $s$ and $t.$* But how does this work? How did they come up with this binomial to begin with? **This binomial coefficient appears before testing the base cases.**

---

**Background info:**

For instance, in [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Combinatorics/Bounds_for_Ramsey_numbers):

Since $R(r, s) ≤ R(r − 1, s) + R(r, s − 1)$ so this automatically gives an upper bound, although not in the closed form that we expect.

The closed form expression is ${\displaystyle R(r,s)\leq {\binom {r+s-2}{r-1}}}.$ To derive this use double induction on $r$ and $s.$ The base case $r = s = 2$ is easily established as $${\displaystyle R(2,2)=2\leq {\binom {2+2-2}{2-1}}=2}.$$

Now assume the expression holds for $R(r − 1, s)$ and $R(r, s − 1).$ Then

$${\displaystyle R(r,s)\leq R(r-1,s)+R(r,s-1)\leq {\binom {r+s-3}{r-2}}+{\binom {r+s-3}{r-1}}={\binom {r+s-2}{r-1}}}$$ gives us our upper bound. Note that we have used Pascal's relation in the last equivalence.

But why did they start already applying the binomial formula they intend to prove in ${\displaystyle R(2,2)=2\leq {\binom {2+2-2}{2-1}}=2},$ and how does the inductive process proceed from that point?

---

I see there are related questions, and in fact, I have tried to contribute with a possible answer as to the proof of a finite [Ramsey number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamseyNumber.html) for every combination of two natural numbers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3449911/276181) to get feedback.

However, I still have problems with the immediately related proof of the inequality ([theorem of Erdős-Szekeres](http://www.numdam.org/article/CM_1935__2__463_0.pdf)):

$$R(s,t) \leq \binom{s+t-2}{s-1}$$

as in [here](http://math.mit.edu/%7Efox/MAT307-lecture05.pdf):

[image]

I see that this inequality is fulfilled by the base cases, as well as $s+t<5,$ but I presume other inequalities could also be fulfilled by the first Ramsey numbers.

---

In the following two answers that I found online it seems as though the Ramsey number on, say $(r,t),$ i.e. $R(r,t)$ is somewhat just replaced by $r$ and $t$ in the combinatorics solution. So I don't get the analogy to Pascal's triangle...

**Solution 1:**

The answer can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3449911/276181):

$$R(k,l) \leq \binom{k+l-2}{k-1}$$

because the recurrence $$R(k,l) \leq R(k-1,l) + R(k,l-1) $$ can be seen as the paths from a point $R(k,l)$ on the grid below to $(1,1):$

[image]

and the [number of ways to get to a point on a lattice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5jwy.png) $(x,y)$ taking off from $(0,0)$ are:

$$\binom{x+y}{x}$$

Here we are moving in the opposite direction, and stopping at $(1,1),$ which reduces the count to:

$$\binom{(x-1)+(y-1)}{x-1}=\binom{x+y-2}{x-1}$$

---

"We’ve placed the value $1$ at each position $(k, 1)$ or $(1, l)$ in this grid, corresponding to the
base case $r(k, 1) = r(1, l) = 1$ of our induction. At the point $(k, l)$ in the grid, we know
that the value $r(k, l)$ at that point is upper-bounded by the sum of the values immediately
below and immediately to the left. Applying this same recurrence to these adjacent nodes,
we see that every left/down path from $(k, l)$ to the boundary will contribute $1$ in the final
sum (corresponding to the value $1$ at the boundary points). Thus, $r(k, l)$ is upper-bounded
by the number of left/down paths to the boundary, which is in turn equal to the number of
left/down paths from $(k, l)$ to $(1, 1),$ which is exactly
$\binom{k+l-2}{k-1}."$

---

**Solution 2:**

From [here](https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/2016/Barton.pdf):

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand where your difficulty lies. It seems you understand the basis cases (small values of $s$ or $t$), and the induction step is written out in the first block of text that you quoted. So what remains to be understood?

Comment: OK; that clarifies the problem. The induction step proves the result for $s$ and $t$ assuming that it holds for $s-1$and $t$ and that it also holds for $s$and $t-1$. So it amounts to an induction on $s+t$. That is, it proves, by induction on $n$, the statement "For all $s$ and $t$ with $s+t=n$, $R(s,t)\leq\binom{s+t-2}{s-1}$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2885351/462).

Comment: As for the appearance of the binomial coefficients, the original paper where the argument appears (the one mentioned in the link above) does not present a combinatorial explanation. Meaning: they appear simply because they satisfy the recurrence relation (with equality rather than inequality as the Ramsey numbers), and therefore they constitute a natural upper bound.

Comment: They came up with it because it is the only expression that satisfies the initial conditions and the recurrence relation, and this is well known.

Comment: Or, equivalently, you can prove the recurrence relation for the binomials combinatorially. If you choose $m$ terms of a family of $n$ elements (you can do this in $n\choose m$ ways), you can do it in two ways: fix an element out of the $n$ ones, say John. There are ${n-1}\choose{m-1}$ ways of choosing the $m$ elements, with John being one of them, and there are ${n-1}\choose m$ ways of choosing the $m$ elements, with John not being one of them.

Comment: Substitute $s,t$ appropriately.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I understand the relation $\binom{n-1}{m-1}+\binom{n-1}{m}=\binom{n}{m}$ and its coming really handy in working out the RHS of the inequality $R(k,l) \leq R(k-1,l) + R(k,l-1),$ but I still don't see how you get to the initial use of a binomial equation for either $R(k-1,l)$ or $R(k,l-1).$

Comment: In terms of "How could someone have come up with the binomial coefficient formula without knowing the answer in advance?"  Sometimes just trying a few examples is a powerful tool!  Once I found the recursive upper bound, the next thing I would probably try would be to just compute what bound I get for $R(k,\ell)$ for (say) $1 \leq k \leq 5$ and $1 \leq \ell \leq 5$.  Once I do this, I can recognize that I'm seeing a lot of binomial coefficients in my values so far, and guess a pattern from there.  Only then would I try and prove the pattern inductively.

Comment: @Kevin P. Costello I wrote an answer which strikes me as correct and satisfying. However, it seems at odds with the grid diagram in the OP, where the calculation stretched from any $R(s,t)$ point to $(1,1),$ as opposed to either $(1,m)$ or $(m,1)$ in my answer. I wonder if you can take a look at my answer, and of course, it would be great to get a formal answer, which no matter how brief, it would allow me to allocate the pending bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the upper bound, you are closest with your solution 1.

We have:

$$R(r,b)\le R(r-1,b) + R(r,b-1)$$

(I am using $r$ for red and $b$ for blue - I find it easier to remember!).

Using the idea of Pascal's triangle, we can extend this into:

$$R(r,b)\le  \left(R(r-2,b) + R(r-1,b-1)\right) + \left(R(r-1,b-1) + R(r,b-2)\right)$$

or:

$$R(r,b)\le  R(r-2,b) + 2R(r-1,b-1) + R(r,b-2)$$

The step takes us to:

$$R(r-3,b)+3R(r-2,b-1)+3R(r-1,b-2)+R(r,b-3)$$

with the next step involving $1,4,6,4,1$, and continue using binomial coefficients, except where we hit the boundaries at $R(1,b)=R(r,1)=1$ and then $R(0,b)=R(r,0)=0$, and this leaves the binomial in question.

From [Known Ramsey numbers](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Combinatorics/Bounds_for_Ramsey_numbers#Known_Ramsey_numbers), you can see the pattern by looking at the anti-diagonals.

Comment: Can you make more explicit the link between $R(r,b)\le  R(r-2,b) + 2R(r-1,b-1) + R(r,b-2)$ and the combinatorial expression?

Comment: The step would be R(r-3,b)+3R(r-2,b-1)+3R(r-1,b-2)+R(r,b-3), and each component 'runs dry' at R(0,b)=0, and so leaves the binomial in question. For a direct correlation, you then need to examine each path to see what is happening, I tried this, you get that both the r and b cliques are inaccessible, there are N ways of doing this, but no real clue as to how to connect N to the graph you need.

Comment: Hey, not to be a pain, but would you mind including the comment in the answer - I'd like to credit you with the bounty.

Answer (score 5):

Note: This answer uses the following terminology:
$r=$number of friends and $s=$number of non friends.

I want to prove that $R(r,s) \le R(r-1,s)+R(r,s-1)$
(using an interpretation in English which might give some insight)

For this, I need to show that there will exist either:
i) group of $r$ mutual friends or
ii) group of $s$ mutual non friends
in a group of $R(r-1,s) + R(r,s-1)$ people.

Suppose this group had you with $R(r-1,s) + R(r,s-1)-1$ other people.

You would have some friends, some non friends. Let's call these two groups F and NF.

I claim that either of the two happen (from Pigeonhole principle):
a) $|F| \ge R(r-1,s)$ or $|NF|\ge R(r,s-1)$
b) $|NF| \ge R(r-1,s)$ or $|F|\ge R(r,s-1)$

Because if this isn't the case then  $|F|+|NF|\le (R(r-1,s)-1) + (R(r,s-1)-1) = (R(r-1,s)+R(r,s-1)-2)$.
But since we started with $R(r-1,s) + R(r,s-1)-1$ other people, this is a contradiction.

If, (a) is true, then you already have a group of $s$ friends!
So, lets analyse (b).
In (b) you have 2 cases:

[image: Group of friends and non friends]

Case 1: if $|F| \ge R(r-1,s)$
This means that amongst your friends there was a group of $r-1$ mutual friends.
Hence, when I include you, I create a group of $r$ friends.

Case 2: $|NF|\ge R(r,s-1)$
This means that amongst your non friends there was a group of $s-1$ people who didn't know each other.
Hence, when I include you, I create a group of $s$ non friends.

Thus, in a group of $R(r-1,s) + R(r,s-1)$ people, there will either be a group of $r$ mutual friends or a group of $s$ mutual non friends. So, $R(r,s) \le R(r-1,s)+R(r,s-1)$.

Comment: This is great, but I need the derivation of the binomial formula. +1

Comment: $R(a+1,b+1)\le\binom {a+b}a$

Answer (score 2):

The inequality $R(r,s) \leq R(r,s-1)+R(r-1,s)$ has been proven in @Harshal's post, and is explained in many different entries online. My difficulty was in the transition from the inequality to the binomial formulation:

$$
{\displaystyle R(r,s)\leq R(r,s-1)+R(r-1,s)\leq {\binom {r+s-3}{r-1}}+{\binom {r+s-3}{r-2}}={\binom {r+s-2}{r-1}}}$$

This is my attempt in the absence of any answers explicitly explaining this combinatorial upper bound:

By symmetry, $R(r,s)=R(s,r),$ which justifies only considering Ramsey numbers where $r>s$ in $R(r,s)$ without loss of generality. Likewise the so-called base cases $R(r,1)=1$ and $R(r,2)=r$ are readily accessible in many online posts to need further consideration. In particular [$R(r,1)=1$](http://web.stanford.edu/~yuvalwig/math/teaching/AreaExam.pdf) almost appears axiomatic:

> As a base case, observe that $r(k, 1) = 1$ for all $k.$ Indeed, in any two-coloring of the edges of $K_1$ (of which there are none), we will always find a (trivial) blue $K_1.$

To bring out an intuition leading to the proof of the formula in question, let me pick an example that is manageable in size, such as $R(5,4),$ and apply recursively the inequality until reaching either $R(m,1)$ or $R(1,m),$ and hence ending up with an expression in which each element contributes $1$ to the value of $R(r,s).$ To make the expressions more compact, $R(r,s)=rs:$

$\begin{align}
\small R(r,s)&\leq R(r,s-1)+R(r-1,s)\\
&\leq \color{red}{53} + \color{blue}{44}\\
&\leq \color{red}{52+43}+ \color{blue}{43+ 34}\\
&\leq \color{red}{51+42+42+33}+ \color{blue}{42+33+ 33+24}\\
&\leq\small\color{red}{51+41+32+41+32+32+23}+ \\
&\small\quad\;\color{blue}{41+32+32+23+32+23+23+14}\\
&\leq\Tiny\color{red}{51+41+31+22+41+31+22+31+22+22+13}+ \\
&\Tiny\quad\;\color{blue}{41+31+22+31+22+22+13+31+22+22+13+22+13+14}\\
&\leq\Tiny\color{red}{51+41+31+21+12+41+31+21+12+31+21+12+21+12+13}+\\
&\Tiny\quad\;\color{blue}{41+31+21+12+31+21+12+21+12+13+31+21+12+21+12+13+21+12+13+14}\\
&= 35
\end{align}$

Evidently, there is overlap in the patterns below certain nodes in the recursive expression that are reached through different paths. For example, notice the repetitive pattern beyond $42:$

$$\begin{align}
&51+\color{orange}{42}+\color{red}{42}+33+ \color{magenta}{42}+33+ 33+24\\
&\leq\small51+\color{orange}{41+32}+\color{red}{41+32}+32+23+ \\
&\small\quad\;\color{magenta}{41+32}+32+23+32+23+23+14\\
&\leq\Tiny{51+\color{orange}{41+31+21+12}+\color{red}{41+31+21+12}+31+21+12+21+12+13}+\\
&\Tiny\quad\;\color{magenta}{41+31+21+12}+31+21+12+21+12+13+31+21+12+21+12+13+21+12+13+14
\end{align}$$

These entries do indeed represent overlapping paths that can be better visualized as follows:

[image]

Many paths are taken multiple times, and each one adds $1$ to the total sum (in red at the margins).

In this way counting the different paths is just a matter of counting the possible trajectories heading right (East) and left (West), but always South. For instance, the $\color{red}6$ different ways of getting to $31$ are

[image]

Notice that they all go through $32$ - after that there are zero degrees of freedom.

To calculate the number of paths is straightforward noticing that the number of ways to get to a node is given by Pascal's triangle:

[image]

So at this point all that remains is summing these coefficients along diagonal lines of Pascal's triangle. To this end, the sum of some values along a diagonal of Pascal's triangle from left and up to right and low is immediately available in the line below. For example the sum of $4$ terms along the third diagonal is:

[image]

$$\binom{2}{0}+\binom{3}{1}+\binom{4}{2}+\binom{5}{3}=\binom{6}{3}$$

Hence we are adding along the row number $R=3$ of Pascal's triangle $N=4$ values, and we can generalize as

$$\small\binom{R-1}{0}+\binom{R-1+1}{1}+\binom{R-1+2}{2}+\cdots+\binom{R-1+N-1}{N-1}=\binom{R+N-2}{N-1}\tag 1$$

This happens to be the $R(r-1,s)$ part of the inequality for $R(5,4)$ because we are adding along the $s-2$ diagonal of Pascal's triangle with $s=4.$ This is apparent in the diagrams above, where the elements along a diagonal reduce the first entry, keeping the second constant.  We want to add along that diagonal exactly $r-1$ elements, which in the example correspond to $5-1=4.$

From $(1)$ it is clear that the sum of these binomials can be calculated directly from Pascal's triangle as

$$\binom{(s-2)+r-1}{(r-1)-1}=\binom{r+s-3}{r-2}$$

To this we have to add the sum along the diagonal in the opposite direction: from right and up to left and down to account for $\binom{3}{3}+\binom{4}{3}+\binom{5}{3},$ corresponding to the $R(r,s-1)$ part of the inequality, but the answer now is also on the row below of Pascal's triangle, but just one step more to the right:

$$\binom{(s-2)+r-1}{r-1}=\binom{r+s-3}{r-1}$$

This can also be seen by symmetry in the diagram below:

[image]

And thus,

$$
{\displaystyle R(r,s)\leq R(r,s-1)+R(r-1,s)= {\binom {r+s-3}{r-1}}+{\binom {r+s-3}{r-2}}={\binom {r+s-2}{r-1}}}\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Comment: This is really good. I was thinking on the lines of having a symmetry in group with r+s-3 people. Will update if I get something! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are only familiar with inducting on a single variable $n$, here's how this can be rewritten, ala comment by Andreas Blass.

> Boundary Lemma: $\forall s, t: R(1,t), R(s,1)$ both $\le {s+t -2 \choose s-1}$

Proof: "every graph contains a clique of size $1$" (quoted from OP first image).  Note that this is in a sense *not* part of the later induction on single $n$ (the way I wrote it).  But IMHO it is more natural to think of the entire boundary as base cases.

> Hypothesis $H(n)$ for $n\ge 4$: $\forall s > 1, t> 1,$ with $s+t=n: R(s,t) \le {s+t -2 \choose s-1}$

We will prove by induction on $n$ that $H(n)$ is valid $\forall n \ge 4$.

> Base case $H(4)$: i.e. $s=t=2$

Proof: See the $R(2,2)$ case in the OP "Theorem 3.3".

> Induction case: proving that $H(n-1) \implies H(n)$

Proof: consider any $s>1, t>1, s+t=n$.  We have $R(s,t) \le R(s-1,t) + R(s,t-1)$.

- Case A: $s-1 >1$.  In this case, $R(s-1,t) \le {s + t - 3 \choose s-2}$ by $H(n-1)$ because $(s-1) + t = n-1$

  - Lemme expand this since this is where you're having trouble.  $H(n-1)$ says $\forall a>1, b>1, a+b=n-1: R(a,b) \le {a+b-2 \choose a-1}$.  Now we substitute $a=s-1, b=t$ and check: Yes they do satisfy $a>1$ (because we're analyzing Case A where $s-1>1$) and $b=t>1$ and finally also $a+b=n-1$.  So by $H(n-1)$ we have $R(a,b) = R(s-1,t) \le {a+b-2 \choose a-1} = {s + t - 3 \choose s-2}$.
- Case B:  $s-1 = 1$.  In this case, $R(s-1,t) \le {s + t - 3 \choose s-2}$ by Boundary Lemma.  (The induction hypothesis $H(n-1)$ is irrelevant here.)
- Conclusion: $R(s-1,t) \le {s + t - 3 \choose s-2}$ whether $s-1 > 1$ or $=1$.
- Similarly, $R(s,t-1) \le {s+t - 3 \choose s-1}$, whether $t-1 > 1$ (by induction) or $t-1=1$ (by Boundary Lemma)

Therefore, for any $s>1, t>1, s+t=n$ we have $R(s,t) \le {s + t - 3 \choose s-2} + {s + t - 3 \choose s-1} \le {s+t -2 \choose s-1}$.  This proves $H(n)$.

---

Hopefully this helps?  Or am I just repeating the same confusion by the quoted authors.

In general, I don't think one needs to be so explicit.  You can induct on several integer variables at once as long as you know that the recurrence eventually reach boundary cases which you prove separately (in this case, via the Boundary Lemma).

Note that you do need to prove the boundary cases.  E.g. if you only proved the $R(1,1)$ case and then use this recurrence, it will not work, because e.g. $R(3,2) \le R(3,1) + R(2,2)$ and you have no info on what happens at $R(3,1)$.  And this is why I prove all the boundary cases in one swoop, and also why even though the boundary is not technically the base case for $H(n)$ (the way I wrote it), IMHO it is natural to think of the entire boundary as base cases.

Comment: I don't see "If $s-1>1$ then $R(s-1,t) \leq {s + t - 3 \choose s-2}$ by $H(n-1)$ because $(s-1) + t = n-1.$" If $s-1>1$ means $2$ or higher, which I guess invokes the base case $H(4),$ even though there are no conditions on $t$? And from there the binomial formula appears, which I guess it is my main hurdle, since I don't see where it came from.

Comment: Not important, but would you kindly consider avoiding stating that things are obvious, as for example "the $R(2,2)$ case is obvious" - it may be, but I would suggest a reference, such as in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1045799/276181), because I have a feeling that the whole OP is very obvious to a lot of people, but not to me, and I still don't know exactly where I'm getting confused.

Comment: (1) I have added more explanation to the key induction step.  Hope it helps?  (2) I have removed the words "obvious".  I was calling them "obvious" only because their proofs were directly quoted in the OP images.  [In fact, they were not obvious to me because I know very little about Ramsey theory.]

Comment: My question boils down to what is the reasoning to think about $ {s + t - 2 \choose s-1}$ in terms of perhaps choosing edges among some set even before we test the base cases.

Comment: I thought your question was about how the induction works.  My answer is purely about how the induction works.  :(  I.e. I can't tell you at all how people invented the _hypothesis_ that $R(s,t) \le {s + t -2 \choose s-1}$ in the first place, but once that's invented, it can be proved inductively, and I thought you had trouble with the logic of the induction, which my answer attempts to clarify.